# Firestore. Как получать данные по нескольким вариантам поля, имитируя оператор OR из SQL?

Tags: java, android, firestore

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE category = 'category1' OR category = 'category2' OR category = 'category3'
```

Возможно ли в одном запросе получить данные у которых поле `category` имеет разные значение?
Оператора OR как такового нет, а `whenEqualTo` три раза подряд не даёт результата.

Answer (score 0):

Да, возможно. Используйте выборку из Firestore:

- .whereEqualTo("someFiled", "somevalue")
- .whereGreaterThan("someFiled", somevalue)
- .whereLessThan("someFiled", somevalue)

Более [детально](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

Comment: Cloud Firestore does not support the following types of queries:

Logical OR queries. In this case, you should create a separate query for each OR condition and merge the query results in your app.